# Should bower packages in Ionic project work on IOS?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, bower

I added two bower packages (angular-md5 and angular-momentjs) to my Ionic project. They work great in Chrome but don't work at all in the iOS Simulator. I'm not exactly sure the proper way to debug these types of issues in the Simulator, if they'd even bubble to the surface because of how the apps are created, or if adding third-party JavaScript libraries is even supported by Ionic. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bower packages are supported by Ionic. In fact, Ionic's library is installed and kept up to date by Bower.

To debug an app running in the iOS Simulator, follow the following instructions (taken from [this simple tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/09/22/ios-safari-web-inspector)):

> 1. In Settings.app on your device, select Safari > Advanced and then enable Web Inspector.
> 2. Connect your device to your computer via your cable.
> 3. Load the web page you want to inspect in Mobile Safari.
> 4. Now, in Safari on your desktop, select Develop > iPhone Simulator and then select the appropriate page from the list.
>
> If you don’t see the Develop menu then you need to enable it in Safari’s Preferences. Select Safari > Preferences > Advanced and check Show Develop menu in menu bar.

When you open the Safari web inspector, you will likely see several errors in the console. The most common mistake, in my experience, is to use absolute paths to include scripts, like so:

```
<script src="/lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
```

Chrome supports absolute paths, but iOS does not. Fix the problem by using a relative path, keeping in mind that `index.html` is at the top level directory:

```
<script src="lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response @Adam Vigneaux I wasn't aware you could debug the Simulator with Safari's debug tools -- very cool! Thanks to your suggestion I was able to get it to work. It turns out angular-momentjs asynchronously loads the standard moment.js library. The script injection code loading that library featured a URL that did not have a protocol specified so it was looking for it in the filesystem. Adding "http:" allowed it to load correctly which eliminated the fatal error that was also causing angular-md5 not to work. Thanks very much!